# Question regarding filter implementation - Audio EQ Cookbook

Tags: filters, filter-design, lowpass-filter, c++

Some of you may know the infamous Audio EQ Cookbook. [You can take a look here.](https://www.w3.org/TR/audio-eq-cookbook/)

We tried to implement the functions there to achieve a  implementation for a Lowpassfilter.
However, when we try to lower our variable cutoff-frequency, we have some issues. With decreasing cutoff-frequency the signal is increasing in volume. Reaching a distinct treshold at around 4000- 6000Hz the filter stops working, because it computes samplevalues that are ever increasing, reaching around 2000000 shortly after lowering the cutoff frequency.

We checked our code multiple times,and the functions from the Cookbook should be right. If someone wants to see the code i can hand it to you later.

For any hints or solution we are more than thankful.

**EDIT:** The important part of the code.

```
float Filter::processFilter(float sample)
{
   float unprocessed = sample;

    float processed = (unprocessed) + (computeB1() * x_n_1) + 
        (computeB2() * x_n_2) - (computeA1() * y_n_1)
        -(computeA2() * y_n_2);

    x_n_2 = x_n_1;
    x_n_1 = unprocessed;

    y_n_2 = y_n_1;
    y_n_1 = processed;


    return processed;
}
```

Comment: What's your Q? Your implementation is in floating point? You could post the filter coefficients so we can see what's going on (or, equivalently, Q, f0, and your sampling frequency).

Comment: That page, you provided, belongs to "Robert Bristow-Johnson" so you better ask him, as he is a member here :)

Comment: Q was 1 when the problem occured. The implementation is in c++ with float type. Sampling frequency is 48000. And f0 is 5355 and every value below that.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, if some information is missing i can provide, but just downvote the question is not helpful, thanks.

Comment: @amaik: I agree about the downvote. Downvoter: any comments?

Comment: Why x_n_1_Right when you update x_n_1 (without 'Right') in your code?

Comment: That's right in the code. A translation mistake when making the sample more readable. Sorry.

Comment: `unprocessed` should be multiplied by `B0`, and all coefficients must be normalized by $a_0$ (which is not equal to $1$).

Comment: I have also checked it and as Matt L suggests, the filter works fine. It is stable. However when A,B coefficients are normalized by A0 and B0, I  observed a gain of 20dB at the pass band, which might be a reason of the transiently increasing sequence you observed at low frequencies

Comment: @BulentS.: The coefficients are only normalized by $a_0$, not by $b_0$.

Comment: @MattL : yes, that's sure true, but I thought he (amaik) might not know it and normalize both sets. Because it seemed to be the only reason to me that he could have an increasing output due to the resulting gain.

Comment: looks like @MattL. hit it pretty squarely regarding b0.  one thing i might mention is that even when you do everything "right", with single-precision floats for the coefficients, there is the *cosine problem*.  just replace every $\cos(\omega_0)$ with $$ \cos(\omega_0) = 1 - 2\left( \sin\left(\frac{\omega_0}{2} \right) \right)^2 $$ and use the "$1$" as a separate signal path in the sample-processing code.  i didn't want to deal with that issue in the cookbook.  i thought it might be a distraction.  but if $\omega_0 \ll 1$, then $\cos(\omega_0)$ has numerical problems.

Comment: Thanks again @all. It seems that my problem is that i completely misfigured what "you will likely normalize a0 to be 1" means. Could you describe how to do this or link to some description.

Comment: @amaik: From the cookbook you get coefficients a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, and b2. Now you divide all coefficients by a0, and that's it. So the final b0 that you use is the original b0 divided by a0, etc.

Comment: @amaik you can find a simple example using matlab in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973467/how-to-build-low-pass-filter-without-using-built-in-function-in-matlab/24999593#24999593)

Comment: One more questions. Is it safe to add two filtered signals with the same filter into one signalpath? It seems that i get horrible tech-sounds, when i try to combine two filtered signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the values you provided ($Q=1$, $f_0=5355\,\text{Hz}$, and $F_s=48\,\text{kHz}$) I get the following filter coefficients from the Cookbook formulas:

```
b =

   0.11789
   0.23578
   0.11789

a =

   1.32248
  -1.52844
   0.67752
```

Note that the formulas give you denominator coefficients that are not normalized. Many implementations use $a_0=1$, which can be easily achieved by dividing numerator and denominator coefficients by $a_0=1.32248$.

The maximum pole radius of this filter is $0.72$, which means that we're not at all close to the unit circle, so stability shouldn't be an issue, no matter which implementation you use.

You can add more information if you like, but from what I know up to now, the most likely problem is a bug in your code.

Just test your filtering routine by using as input sequence `x=1,0,0,...,`, which should give the following output (the impulse response):

```
ans =

   8.9144e-02
   2.8131e-01
   3.6860e-01
   2.8188e-01
   1.3694e-01
   1.3860e-02
  -5.4140e-02
  -6.9672e-02
  -5.2786e-02
  -2.5313e-02
  -2.2122e-03
   1.0411e-02
   1.3166e-02
   9.8827e-03
   4.6767e-03
   3.4194e-04
  -2.0007e-03
  -2.4875e-03
  -1.8499e-03
  -8.6361e-04
  -5.0389e-05
```

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I'll check again for bugs. Just one more question. y[n] does specify the effected signal, whilst x[n] the uneffected signal, doesn't.

Comment: @amaik: Yes, $x[n]$ is the input sequence, and $y[n]$ is the output sequence.

Comment: Thanks again. I checked the computation of the coefficients and we have the same as you posted. I edited the question and added the important part of the code. What may be false is the output sequence? I don't know.

Comment: @amaik: OK, I added the output signal for an impulse as input signal. Compare that with what you're routine computes.